# How to cross compile redis for ARM on Ubuntu?

Tags: redis, arm, cross-compiling

I have downloaded redis-5.0.6 on Ubuntu and tried to compile redis in x86_64 and the redis-server could work appropriately. Now I need to cross compile it and run it in ARM 32bits linux system

I have tried to install `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` and add `CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` in Makefile before compiling but it didn't work. There is no ./configure in redis path so I don't know how to regenerate `Makefile`

Comment: Have you tried cross-toolchain provided by Arm at https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads?

Comment: What didn't work? Pleas provide output.

Answer (score 1):

An aging question, but worth sharing some information for others...

This is still an open issue with Redis, see [this](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/5273) and [this](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/6014).

A workaround would be to statically build it on a similar machine, say a raspberry pi.
Then copy the directory of binaries over to your target host similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732783/how-do-i-compile-redis-so-that-i-can-upload-and-run-it-on-shared-hosting).

```
make distclean && make CFLAGS="-static" EXEEXT="-static" LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/" PREFIX=~/_build/
```

Any missing shared objects on the target, try to find and copy from debian.org